# What do these D's mean?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So in my dump some items are marked with a pink D. Some are not. What does it mean?

[image: What do these D's mean?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means they have been marked for dumping, and your dwarves with the garbage hauling labor enabled will haul it off to your garbage dump as soon as possible.

You can select them like you have in your screenshot and press <kbd>d</kbd> to toggle dumping, or use <kbd>o</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> to do it to an entire area.

Comment: These items are already in my dump.

Comment: @aslum That does not change the fact they have been marked for dumping. Nothing will happen so long as they're forbidden, though.

Comment: I guess my question then is why are some items not marked w/ the D? How would stuff get in my dump that wasn't dumped?

Comment: @aslum - You mark an item with `D` to specify that the dwarves should pick it up and drop it in a dump. After they do that, items are no longer marked as `D` and become marked as `F` (forbidden). If an item is in a dump, but marked as `D` and not `F`, dwarves will pick each one up and drop it again in the same spot.